# Getting an element by specific attribute itself

Tags: javascript

Here is the element inside my div:

```
<div aria-label="Chart">
  <a opacity="0.4" aria-labelledby="id-71-title" style="cursor: pointer;" transform="translate(0,500)" filter="url(&quot;#filter-id-71&quot;)"></a>
 <a opacity="0.4"></a>
</div>
```

How can I select the element with  `aria-labelledby` attribute?

Note that we can simply select the element via that attribute but I want to only select the element inside the `aria-label="Chart"` with `aria-labelledby` attached to it?

Is this possible with JavaScript?

Edit:

I'm using this and it works fine but I know there should be a better way:

```
const parent = document.querySelector(`[aria-label="Chart"]`).nextSibling.childNodes[0].children;
parent.forEach(e => {
    if(e.hasAttribute('aria-labelledby')) console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: JavaScript or CSS?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [CSS selectors](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Comment: @Sebastian Simon Tell us where on that doc I can get the element by its attr itself?

Comment: @SaraRee [Attribute selectors](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and [Descendant combinator](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator).

Comment: @Sebastian Simon please have a look at the question's tag...

Comment: @SaraRee CSS selectors can be used in JavaScript, using [`querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), which is the easiest way to select elements, e.g. with `"[aria-label='Chart'] [aria-labelledby]"`. I’m not sure why you’re accessing `nextSibling`; did you read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) of what it does?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("[aria-label='Chart'] [aria-labelledby]")`?

Comment: No I want that specific `aria-labelledby` inside `aria-label="Chart"`

Comment: @SaraRee _“I want that specific `aria-labelledby` inside `aria-label="Chart"`”_ — The attribute value or the element? Where exactly are you stuck now? The difference between `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`? `getAttribute`? Everything you need has already been mentioned and linked.

Comment: I want the element via with `aria-labelledby` attr attached to it...

Comment: Just try what I've suggested above, you will have a NodeList.

Comment: Returns the wrong element not that inside ...

Comment: `var el = document.querySelectorAll("[aria-label='Chart'] [aria-labelledby]"); console.log([...el][0]);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`document.getElementById('parent-element').querySelector("[aria-labelledby]")`​

Comment: after the first answer why would you do this one?

Comment: as per the first answer the child element to be a direct child it will not work with siblings

Comment: just ditch the > and leave a space

Comment: Produces an error: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: @SaraRee No, it does not.

Comment: I updated my question Please use my new element: `<div aria-label="Chart">`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

```
document.querySelector('#parent-element > [aria-labeledby="id-71-title"]')
```

This query returns the child of the element with and ID of parent-element, that has an aria-labeledby with a value of 'id-71-title'.

Comment: It is more correct to say _direct children_ as opposed to _child_.

Comment: I told you I want to select the element only via aria-labeledby , I don't have the `id-71-title`!!!!

Comment: @RobMoll “Direct children” is redundant; “children” has a clear meaning. All children are descendants; _direct descendants_ are children. `document.querySelector` with a `>` selector doesn’t return _children_, it returns _a single child_, or `null`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I must be misreading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators#child_combinator).

Comment: @RobMoll Well, that’s something that can be edited in the [MDN repo](//github.com/mdn/content/blob/main/files/en-us/learn/css/building_blocks/selectors/combinators/index.html).

Comment: @SebastianSimon I see your point. While `>` returns all direct children, `document.querySelector`  returns the first element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors.